# Creating a dotted ball texture

Tags: 3d, geometry, textures

I made a simple dot pattern with Paint.net:

[image]

Which obviously looks wrong on a sphere (using UV = (phi / 2pi, theta / pi)):

[image]

I supose I have to distort the image somehow, but how? How do I modify (or generate) a texture so it looks good on a sphere?

(ps: ignore the top vertex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the opposite of the [map projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections) problem, and as you can see from that link, there are no perfect solutions to map between a 2D texture and a 3D sphere surface. Pick the mapping that you can deal with the best (and is supported by your 3D toolkit or API) and modify your source texture to match.

[Here](http://vterrain.org/Textures/spherical.html) is a nice article on different spherical texture mapping techniques. I like the ones that don't treat the pole as special (like icosahedral).

And [here](http://www.blitzbasic.com/Community/posts.php?topic=63686) is an article on how to vary your texture for better results.